# Что надо чтобы написать функцию прямого обращения к мыше или клавиатуре?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Ситуация такая есть у меня библиотека-кликер и я хочу написать несколько функций которые бы работали не через winapi эмулируя клавиатуру, мышь (это уже и так написал) а напрямую , как то так. Все потому что многие игры используют системы зашиты не дают эмулировать передвижение мыши или нажатие клавиатуры. Библиотека у меня на Qt, все для него. Я немного посидел и пришел к выводу что надо копать в сторону написания драйверов на Windows. Только даже не представляю что и как его писать, да еще чтобы это как то в библиотеку впихнуть. Может есть какие нибудь статьи или что-нибудь именно на эту тему. Я знаю что есть программки кликеры и там это реализовано, например Kibor

Comment: прямое обращение с под ОС? нет, не нужно. Лучше вот это https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard - отследить програмно конечно можно, но для многих "защит" будет "неожиданно".

Comment: Будем пробовать, спс

Comment: Ничего не пойму и как мне это в свою библиотеку перетянуть, это ж только для Arduino или нет?

Comment: да, это для ардуино. А она подключается по usb и выглядит как полноценная клавиатура/мыша.